# Change the value in WPF textbox if it exceeds an int value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I have created some validation rules such as some of the text fields being required to have a field input, the fields with numbers will only accept int values etc. Right now, I'm trying to achieve the following:

If the value in a couple of textboxes that require int in them exceeds 65,000, the textbox should automatically convert it back to 65000. So for instance if I type 65,200, that textbox should change it back to 65,000.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPort" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="25,25,25,5">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="White" materialDesign:ValidationAssist.Background="White" materialDesign:HintAssist.Foreground="#FF002655" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextFieldTextBox}" Width="250" x:Name="txtboxWebsitePort" TextChanged="txtboxWebsitePort_TextChanged" PreviewTextInput="txtboxWebsitePort_PreviewTextInput">
        <Binding Path="WebsitePort" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:IntegerValidation ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

```
        private void txtboxWebsitePort_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }
```

```
    public class IntegerValidation : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string valueAsString = value as string;
                if ((!valueAsString.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsLetter)) && (valueAsString.Length > 0) && ((Convert.ToInt64(value) == 0)))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Invalid Value.");
                }                
                else if (valueAsString.Length > 0)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(true, null);
                }
                else if ((valueAsString.Length > 0) && (Convert.ToInt54(value) >= 65000))
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be greater than 65000);
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any class resposnsible for data holding/changing?

Comment: What is `IntegerValidation`? *Validation* means to display the error, not changing (limiting) entered value. If you use MVVM, then the job would be a simple check in the property setter bound to `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: @Sinatr I've updated the question and added `IntegerValidation`.

Comment: @MaciejLos No just that validation. I've added that in the question now.

Comment: You didn't show `WebsitePort`. Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: Why not just disallow values > 65M in the property setter?

Comment: Do you *really* want that behaviour? It can be quite annoying when you get into situations as user where you have to find out an algorithm how to fix your value without endlessly being overwritten by the validation checker. For example: Are you sure "mark 2 digits and press one digit to replace them" works properly when being at the limit?

Answer (score 2):

You should never magically change user input. This does never provide a good experience. It's bad practice in terms of UI design.

The proper way is to give an error feedback and let the user himself correct his input. This gives the user back the full control and interacting with your interface doesn't feel like a strange bug.

Anyway, you have different options to override the input by force.

To override user input you can:

1. handle the `TextBox.TextChanged` event to override the input while typing.
2. handle `TextBox.PreviewTextInput` event to override the input while typing (important: defer execution of the handler by delegating the call to the dispatcher using `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`).
3. handle the `Control.LostFocus` event to override the input after typing is completed
4. use data binding by binding `TextBox.Text` to a data model or code-behind (dependency) property, which allows you to intercept or override the value assigned to a property's set method

Example:

```
<TextBox LostFocus="TextInput_LostFocus" />


private void TextInput_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
  int numericValue = int.Parse(textBox.Text);
  if (numericValue > 65000)
  {
    textBox.Text = 65000.ToString();
  }
}
```

Note that a validation error message should tell the user why his input is wrong so that he knows how to correct it. *"Invalid value"* is not a good meaningful error message. `"Value must be numeric"` on the other hand gives the user a clear idea what exact input is expected and how to fix the invalid input.

To test if a string is a number simply use  `int.TryParse("123", out int numericResult)`:

```
public bool IsNumber(string textValue) => int.TryParse(textValue, out _);
```

To test if the input is empty (or `null`), simply use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("")`.

This way you validation can be significantly simplified:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
  var textInput = value as string;

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textInput))
  {
    return new ValidationResult(false, "Input cannot be empty");
  }

  if (!int.TryParse(textInput, out _))
  {
    return new ValidationResult(false, "Input must be numeric");
  }

  return new ValidationResult(true, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I made some changes to the ValidationRule and now it's working. Along with that, I've also set a Maximum Character limit to 5 characters. However, the LostFocus method does not seem to be working and I cannot pin why.

Comment: Wahat exactly is not working? Please review your edit: `Convert.ToInt54(value) >= 65000`. First `ToInt54` does not exist. `>= 65000` will make the validation fail when '65000' was enetered, which is a valid value.

Comment: I can asure you that Lost Focus works. Maybe you should edit your answer and add your current version.

Comment: If you say "not working", can please provide more details what exactly is not working and what is actually happening?

Comment: The reason why your validation failed to produce the expected result is the order of the conditional checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can as offered by *lidqy* in comment reset the value in `WebsitePort` setter, so you will handle this in model or viewmodel, or you can do it also in view with a simple converter:

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
    
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is string str && Int32.TryParse(str, out int valInt) && parameter is int limit)
        {
            if(valInt > limit)
            {
                return limit;
            }
            return value;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

XAML then can looks like:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="WebsitePort" Converter="{StaticResource LimitValueCnv}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <Sys:Int32>65000</Sys:Int32>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```